# Replace background size with jquery on fluid layout

Tags: jquery, html, css, fluid-layout

I have a website where I'm using fluid layout, in one of the `<div>` called `#main_picture` is has a background image which resizes depend on the size of the window.

I want to set the height of the div `#main_picture` after the height of the background image

I already tried this code but it throws a error of Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token;

Hope someone has a better idea which can help

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var size = $('#main_picture').css('background-size');
    $("#main_picture").css({ 
        "background-size": size;
    });
});
```

Comment: remove the semicolon after size

Comment: oh thanks well, it worked without error, now i just realised that the val size returns "cover" and i will like to know the real height of it

Comment: var size = $('#main_picture').height();

Comment: that is the height from the div i want to know the height from the background image

Comment: Is there an image tag inside of the main_picture div or is that the image?

Comment: @user3926345 add your `HTML` also. that we can realized what is the issue

Comment: Any chance that you could use a CSS3 solution?

Answer (score -1):

there is a simple syntax error you have to use, you are using unwanted ; after size in css attribute definition

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var size = $('#main_picture').css('background-size');
    $("#main_picture").css({ 
        "background-size": size
});
});
```

or you can try this but this not the good way and this do the same

```
 "background-size": ""+size+""
```